# How to horizontally and vertically center an image inside a scrollview in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Imagine a simple scrollview that contains a content view with an image in it which should be centered vertically **if height is smaller than the scrollview's height**.

If the image **exceeds the height of the scrollview** the scrollview should allow scrolling to display the complete image.

Additionally if the image is narrower than its container it should be **centered horizontally**.

When being scaled down the image should always retain its **intrinsic aspectRatio**.

These are the requirements

How would you do that in SwiftUI?

##### What are the problems that need to be tackled here?

- content views of scrollviews are not automatically centered, they are aligned top-leading
- resizable images always take all the space they get, even if intrinsically smaller than its frames (thus they scale up, which is nasty)
- the aspect ratio of the image needs to be as it was originally
- if the image gets taller than the scrollview itself the content needs to be scrollable to reveal the whole image

##### What should not be part of the solution:

- pinch to scale

---

Similar issues on Stackoverflow (not really solving the issue):

- [SwiftUI How to vertically center a view inside a VStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64266470/swiftui-how-to-vertically-center-a-view-inside-a-vstack)

Answer (score 2):

One suggested solution would be the following:

```swift
struct TestView: View {

    let image: UIImage

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ScrollView {
                SwiftUI.Group {
                    Image(uiImage: self.image)
                        // make image resizable to expand to frame's bounds
                        .resizable()
                        // make sure the aspect ratio when scaling is
                        // like the original image ratio
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        // limit the image's width to its intrinsic width
                        // this gets rid of **upscaling**
                        .frame(maxWidth: image.size.width)

                }
                // makes sure the container is always at least as tall as the scrollview
                // so that the **vertical alignment** works properly
                // additionally we let the frame expand horizontally to the edges of
                // the scrollview for horizontal centering to work                
                .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width, minHeight: geo.size.height)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comments have been added to explain each commands purpose.